# Dynamic feature. Error: failed processing manifest

Tags: android, module, kotlin

I have a base module and I'd wanted to create feature one which contains some libs. One of this libs was into the base module and when I moved it to the feature and removed it from base one I got an error:

> APT: error: resource style/SDKTheme.Translucent (aka
>   io.app.dev.debug:style/SDKTheme.Translucent) not found.

It works if base and feature modules have this dependency, but in this case I lost a profit of separating.

I found a known issue:

> In a dynamic feature module’s manifest, you should not reference
>   resources that don’t exist in the base module. That’s because, when
>   Google Play generates your app’s base APK, it merges manifests for all
>   modules into that of the base APK. So, resource linking breaks if the
>   base APK’s manifest references resources that don’t exist in the base
>   APK.

is this my problem?

Comment: Are you using product flavors or different build types?

Comment: both, I think it shouldn't affect it though

Comment: Can you please point to the source of the known issue you described above?

Comment: @SvenJacobs https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle/ bottom of page

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, that exactly is your problem.

Solutions are:

1. Have the actual implementation of your style in your feature module, but create an empty declaration of the style in your base module. Example of how the empty declaration will look is:

`<style name="SDKTheme.Translucent" />`

What happens is that the manifest merger picks up this style during merging, even though the actual implementation of the style is being introduced through the feature module’s styles.

2. Keep style declarations in the base module. Although, this only works if all resources referenced are in the base module as well.

For more information, read this blog post by Ben Weiss - https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/a-patchwork-plaid-monolith-to-modularized-app-60235d9f212e

Comment: I can confirm that this work around works. Very odd, but works.